# Copying contents of an arrayList and placing them into an array without using java.util.set

Tags: arrays, arraylist, copy

I was wondering if it was possible to take an arrayList and convert it into an array without using java.util.set or any of its descendants in java. I know that there is a method called toArray() that can accomplish this but I want to see if it's possible without using it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public Object[] convertToArray(ArrayList arrayList){
int size = 0;
for(Object o : arrayList)
   size ++;
Object[] result = new Object[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++){
  result[i] = arrayList.get(i);
}
return result;
}
```

Not tested, but is this what you are looking for. Or something differen

Comment: I can't use size() since it's apart of java.util.set

Comment: Heh... what about that?

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?